# Can we preserve the colour code when exporting a list into excel sheet

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, excel, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a custom list where I applied a color coding for some fields as follow inside modern UI:

[image]

But if I export the list as excel, the color code for the fields will be lost. As follow:

[image]

So is there a way to preserve the color code inside excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible using the out of the box **Export to excel** functionality.